# Vue js is not working in my laravel 5.5 application

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

This is my first time to use Vue js and i do not have any idea why it does not work. I been trying to use the default codes in my Laravel Application.

Here is my code in `app.js`:

```
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));
```

Here is my code in ExampleComponent.vue file:

```
    <template>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Example Component</div>

                        <div class="panel-body">
                            I'm an example component!
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is my code for the view:

```
<div id="app">
<example-component></example-component>
</div>
```

And when i run npm run watch it says successful. Any help would be appreciated. I really need help. Thanks.

Comment: What you browser console says ?

Comment: how do you mean by Vue js is not working, you should state clearly what the problem is, when you serve your project, is it blank on the browser
if so, check your routes/web.php file for the route that leads to '/' and ensure the page to render is the right page that has the <div id="app></div>"